Как защитить SPA от парсинга?
Планируем построить SPA на Nuxt/Vue.js на фронте и Laravel для API.
И вопрос защиты от парсинга пока не можем решить.
Есть 2 проблемы, которые мы пытаемся решить:

API должен убедиться
что запросы получает с сайта а не из других источников
(curl,postman,php).
Блокировать открытие сайта в эумляторов
браузеров, например ломанный Selenium.

Остальные вопросы решает платная защита от Cloud Flare.

Это технически невозможно

не решает Cloud Flare, при правильном подходе со стороны парсинга и автоматического контроля

Полностью защититься нельзя, но можно сильно осложнить жизнь тем, кто пытается получить информацию: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34828465/276994

во первых как уже сказали выше - это невозможно. всегда есть более высокий уровень абстракции(в контексте парсинга есть рерайтеры на фрилансе). во вторых даже если от каких то определённых видов парсинга поставите защиту, она вполне может "защищать" и от обычных посетителей. к примеру защита CF регулярно тригерится и на обычный сёрфинг, потому те сайты которые хостятся у них обхожу стороной(хз что ей не нравится в моём Firefox). ну и в третьих всегда найдётся некий % пользователей которые обычным образом не сёрфят из-за удобства, принципов, инвалидности, фаз луны или чего угодно еще.
